# How to access the content of /apple-app-site-association in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am following https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

How would I get Ember to serve this url https://www.some-url.com/app-app-site-association

Note, `app-app-site-association` is a file. Unfortunately, Apple chose not to append an extension to this file.

Ideally, accessing this url should render:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
      "details": [
        {
        "appID": "9F32916B95.foo.bar.baz",
        "paths": ["*"]
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Just add the file to the `public` folder

Comment: @Lux add the file to the public folder? If so, don't I have to modify something on the router.js?

Answer (score 3):

The important think here to understand is that if you want to deliver a static file, may it be your `/app-app-site-association` or just an image on `/something.jpg` this has nothing to do with ember.

Ember runs in the browser. So the entire ember routing happens in the browser. Thats why you have to configure your webserver in a way that it serves the `index.html` file when he does not find a file.

So when you enter `example.com/something` this will trigger a `HTTP GET example.com/something`. Your webserver then *should* check if the file `something` exists, if yes it should respond with `200 OK` and the content of that file.

If if does *not find* the file `something` it would normally respond with a `404 NOT FOUND`. However when you use an SPA as ember you configure your webserver so it will *never* respond with `404 NOT FOUND` but instead return `200 OK` and the body of the `index.html`. ([you can see an example configuration in the ember guides, but this will be different for different webservers](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/basic-use/deploying/))

This then will load your ember app (you've included the `.js` file in the `index.html`) and ember will check the current url and start the ember routing. This *happens in the browser*.

So if *something* wants to make an HTTP request and get the file `app-app-site-association`, it does probably not want to get your `index.html` and then run a browser to let ember do anything. It just wants the file *directly* from your webserver. So your webserver must directly respond with `200 OK` and the content of that file. And it will probably do this as I mentioned above if that file just exists.

Now ember projects have a `public` folder. If you want to have some files alongside your ember application that should just be served by your webserver this is the right place. Whatever you put in it will just be copied to the `dist` folder. This means when you then deploy your `dist` folder you will also deploy the file.

However be careful about your webserver configuration. Because the file has no ending it will probably be served as `text/plain`. If you want it to be served as `application/json` you need to configure your webserver accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much for the wonderful answer. You've been very helpful to my questions ever since. Cheers mate :)